# my type Exception report http status 500

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish-3

HTTP Status 500 -

Type: Exception report

Description

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /modules/Home.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 48] The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /modules/Home.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 48] The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

I am using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2

Comment: post xhtml if you want us to help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obvious:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Go through the code on your `Home.xhtml` page and look for any unclosed tags.